# Which segmentations are there for sports?

Tags: rules

As far as I know, people playing different sports can be separated by age, sex, and sometimes weight. Are there any other segmentations/categories in any sport?

Comment: Do the various disability categories in the Paralympics count?

Comment: Skill level is a segmentation in leagues and/or tournaments.

Comment: Sometimes there are two different leagues based on whether or not the athletes get paid money to play or not.